# How to persist runtime changes made to Delphi's components?

Tags: delphi, runtime, persistence

Every time i add text to a listbox or listview or a button from the editor it appears on every program launch as it should. The question is why when i add them at runtime and then restart the program this items disappear ( text or buttons ). I know the text can be saved in file but is there any other way like its saved default from the editor.

Comment: I think you want do add some items to a listbox, based on an algorithm (all the values some sort of similarity) and make it available always.

Comment: Doing what you're asking can become a fairly advanced topic, and you sound like you're at a very basic level.   Whatever inputs you used to call functions that create the controls need to be persisted (saved to a file on disk or a registry key) and reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the text at design time it is saved in the .dfm file and compiled into the program. This does not happen at runtime.

Imagine if it did. It couldn't really operate in the same way because you can't have the executable changing once you have deployed the app. You would not want user settings to be stored in the executable. So these settings really need to be external to the application.

To make this happen you need to implement your own persistence mechanism. You would need to save the runtime added contents to a file somewhere (e.g. under the user profile) and then re-load this whenever the application starts.

Comment: @Martin That would be one way to achieve what I outline in para 3. The downsides which you outline are a bit drastic though. I think I'd want to maintain tighter control of the .dfm files that my app loads.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well, it's fairly easy to just disable the streaming when required during development - a command-line parameter 'noStream', for example, or a conditional compile. There are other pluses - if you stream the forms as text, you can look at the properties with Notepad or have them emailed to you.  This is occasionally useful when debugging a customer installation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've been doing this for years.  Descend from TForm and override create and destroy. In the dtor, stream out the entire form with Tstream.WriteComponent(), (and call inherited!).  Use the form classname, or some derivative, to assemble the filename.

In create, assemble the filename again and check if a stream file exists for the form.  If not, just call the inherited create() so that the form is created 'normally'. If the file does exist, call CreateNew() and then stream in the form using Tstream.ReadComponent.

This will effectively save and restore all the published properties.  The size, position color, font, text, caption etc. of the form and all its components become persistent.  An app will start up looking exactly the same as when it was shut down.  Labels, lists, memo text, images etc. are all automagically persisted across sessions without any extra code being written.

If you put your new 'TpersistentForm' class in a unit, you can easily make an existing app 'persistent' by adding your 'persist' unit to the uses clause of the form units, edit the form class from 'TForm' to 'TpersistentForm' and rebuild - an 'instant' persistent application by adding one unit and changing a class.

I use this on nearly all my Delphi apps.  It impresses the users no end when an app starts up in the same position, font etc. as when it was last closed.  Also, I don't need any code to store configuration data - the file paths etc. in TEdits etc. just pop right back up - I don't need no nasty and complex INI files or registry!

There are downsides, which you will find out if you try this.  One is design/development time - you test your half-built app and it works fine, so you add some extra buttons, labels to do new stuff, and re-run the app - the new components are not there! This happens because the stream file saved from the previous run does not contain the properties for the new components :((

Comment: Ideally, that should be combined with writing into memory-mapped dfm resource.

Comment: @user Memory mapped files? Why would that be needed? Sounds over the top.

Comment: This is clearly giving advanced advice to a non-advanced developer, and so I think you should warn off the noobs; this is a terrible idea, unless you're an advanced developer.

Comment: @WarrenP - most devleopers, no matter what their level of skill/experience, can get some idea of whether to tackle some job or not.  For example I've been developing for decades but I don't like to touch anything but the simplest SQL.  I don't think it's such a bad idea to avoid the misery of writing, testing and maintaining INI files and/or Registry code and replace it with adding a unit and editing a class name.  I consider reading/writing config just gunge work. I have now to do all that on an embedded C++ job and it's a real pain to continually manage config in the SD-card 'INI files'.

Comment: @user539484 - I just use plain old files, as suggested by David H. Actually, I use a folder tree and files.  The root folder named after the app and sub-folders named for the form and sub-form classnames. This allows multiple instances of the forms at any level to be auto-persisted and auto-recreated on startup.  I will agree with Warren, though, that this solution is not really noob-friendly.

Comment: BTW, [noob and newb terms](http://v.cdn.cad-comic.com/comics/cad-20060823-d025d.jpg) are quite far from being synonyms :-) I have no idea why @WarrenP decided to classify an OP as a noob.

Comment: I classify the OP as a noob because the OP has asked a question that I would not expect to hear an advanced developer express surprise about;  I created some object at runtime, and it isn't saved.  The items disappear. Object lifetime, dynamic, static, designtime, runtime, these concepts are not fuzzy for an advanced developer.

Comment: @WarrenP, i presume you can demonstrate a contrast by showing us how easy persistence can be implemented in VCL :-)

Comment: The way it works here is that when people ask questions, they do them NOT in a comment. So if you weren't being rhetorical, then ask an actual question. It's free, no charge.

Comment: @MartinJames +1 Any chance of yoour making such a TPersist freely available? Maybe a sourceForge projecct or such?